# Could not find the ColdFusion component or interface?

Tags: facebook, api, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am using ColdFusion 10, Windows 7 64bit, Railo 4 and installed the [Facebook CF SDK](https://github.com/affinitiz/facebook-cf-sdk). When I try to test the installation, it is throwing this error:

```
Could not find the ColdFusion component or interface facebook.sdk.FacebookApp.

Ensure that the name is correct and that the component or interface exists.

The error occurred in C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/wwwroot/facebook-cf-sdk/examples/website/index.cfm: line 34
32 : } else {
33 :    // Create facebookApp instance
34 :    facebookApp = new FacebookApp(appId=APP_ID, secretKey=SECRET_KEY);
35 : 
36 :    // See if there is a user from a cookie or session
```

How do I fix this error and integrate this Facebook API with ColdFusion?

Comment: How are you using ColdFusion 10 and Railo 4?  Should be one or the other.  Did you follow the [installation instructions for the Facebook CF SDK](https://github.com/affinitiz/facebook-cf-sdk/wiki/Installation)?

Comment: They could be running both. Though clearly this specific error is occurring under CF10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like an error in the instructions, instead of having the folder be called `facebook-cf-sdk` rename it to `facebook` as that's where it's looking for the cfc at.

Answer (score 1):

Busches' answer should definitely solve the problem. The other alternative is to modify the **imports** to match your directory structure:

*facebook-cf-sdk / examples / website / index.cfm*

```
<cfscript>
import "facebook-cf-sdk.sdk.FacebookApp";
import "facebook-cf-sdk.sdk.FacebookGraphAPI";
```

*facebook-cf-sdk / examples / website / tags.cfm*

```
<cfimport taglib="/facebook-cf-sdk/sdk/tags" prefix="facebook" />
<cfscript>
import "facebook-cf-sdk.sdk.FacebookApp";
import "facebook-cf-sdk.sdk.FacebookGraphAPI";
```

The quotes are needed for component paths that contain hyphens.

Hope this helps,
- Minh